# How to print one specific Javascript variable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to ask how I can print a Javascript variable in HTML form (e.g. output it on the screen)?

Here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
</script>
```

This `var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();` is Jquery variable!

So how i can show this value in HTML page?

Comment: print to the page or the console or print where?

Comment: how i can show this value in HTML page?

Comment: You can create a new text node, use `innerHTML`, `innerText` in selected browsers, `document.write` in selected environments, or use a library like jQuery. Take your pick.

Comment: Can you please give me JS viddle how the whole HTML and JS script will look like?

Comment: NOTE: There's no such thing as a "Jquery variable".  It's a "*JavaScript* variable".

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's just semantics. I think we know what the OP means. In fact calling it a 'jQuery variable' gives us some useful info.

Answer (score 4):

Set it to be the innerHTML or value of a html element:

```
var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
var displayEl = document.getElementById("duration");
displayEl.innerHTML = howLongIsThis;
```

or if you want in in a form field:

```
displayEl.value = howLongIsThis;
```

Comment: My <div id='duration'></div> must be before this scirpt?
How the whole html file with the script will look like? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2979725 JavaScript is generally unlike how PHP or similar is used in HTML documents. You typically have a HTML page, and then the JavaScript runs afterwards and modifies the HTML as needed. So you would create your `div` element, and then right at the end of your document run JavaScript to populate it with data.

Comment: @user2979725 I assumed you already have a html page (where is myPlayer.duration() coming from?) The element `#duration` must be *somewhere* within the `body`. The script can be in the `body` at some point *after* the div or in the `head`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `<div id="example"></div>` somewhere in your HTML, you want to run JavaScript after the DOM has loaded which adds the value you want to that `div`. In jQuery (which you specified in your question you're using), this would simply be:

```
$('div#example').html(myPlayer.duration());
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyanJW/QjXKL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

your HTML

```
<input type="text" id="logId" />
<div id="logId1"></div>
```

js Script

```
var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
document.getElementById("logId").value=howLongIsThis;
document.getElementById("logId1").innerHTML=howLongIsThis;
```

hope this will give you an idea to solve your problem