# Display video duration from videoJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, video.js

I am working on an HTML5 video player with jQuery. For now I have my video player working very well but I want to get the variable for the video duration and show/display it in pure HTML page.

So from here you can take more info about this Jquery video player:
http://www.videojs.com/docs/api/

I think the variable for video duration is: `myPlayer.duration();`

How I can display this value in HTML?

Here is my HTML code to display the player:

```
  <video id="vemvo-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay="true" width="950" height="534"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="[var.base_url]/uploads/[var.video_play]" type='video/flv' />
  </video>
```

This is what I have tried to display this variable but it says that it is = "0" when on the video player it says that it's 4min:

```
  <video id="vemvo-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay="true" width="950" height="534"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="[var.base_url]/uploads/[var.video_play]" type='video/flv' />
  </video>
<div id="duration"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    _V_("vemvo-player").ready(function(){
        var myPlayer = this;
        var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
        $('#duration').html('Duration: ' + howLongIsThis);
    });
</script>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you create a demo of your problem online, maybe on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so we can see it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display Javascript/Jquery value in HTML page? VideoJs Display durration of the video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915141/how-to-display-javascript-jquery-value-in-html-page-videojs-display-durration-o)

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [How to print one specific Javascript variable in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910095/how-to-print-one-specific-javascript-variable-in-html). Please avoid asking the same question multiple times. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915141/how-to-display-javascript-jquery-value-in-html-page-videojs-display-durration-o

Answer (score 6):

You can try this. It works for me.

```
var myPlayer = videojs('vemvo-player');

    if (myPlayer.readyState() < 1) {
        // wait for loadedmetdata event
        myPlayer.one("loadedmetadata", onLoadedMetadata);
    }
    else {
        // metadata already loaded
        onLoadedMetadata();
    }
    
    function onLoadedMetadata() {
        alert(myPlayer.duration());
        $('#duration').html("Duration: " + myPlayer.duration());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var player = videojs('my-video', {
    fluid:false, // videojs settings
    controls:true,
    height: '300'          
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(player.duration()); 
 // will return video duration. Can't be used while page is loading.

  console.log(player.currentTime()); 
 // will return current time if video paused at some time. Intially it would be 0.

});
```

Comment: Your answer should have an explanation.

Comment: Hope those comments will help you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was having troubles to get the **real** duration of videos (using videojs v7.18.*) resulting in bugged custom progressbar! The problem was that `player.duration()` always returns rounded number while `player.liveTracker.seekableEnd()` returns the real value but only after `start` event.

For example, if real duration is 13.456s, these values are returned for videojs player object `p`:

```
                            | On ready    | On load | On start
----------------------------|-------------|---------|----------
p.duration()                | 0           | 14      | 14
p.liveTracker.seekableEnd() | 14          | 14      | 13.456
```

I've ended up with this solution in React:

```
const onDurationChange = () => {
  const dur = player?.liveTracker.seekableEnd() || player?.duration() || 0;
  setDurationInSec(dur);
}

return <video ref={videoRef} onDurationChange={onDurationChange}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who might come here and are using videojs with Vue 3, also might work with similar frameworks like React.

Referring to this code and component usage - https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-vue.html you can do the following changes to get the duration, height, and width.

```
// New Code here
this.player = videojs(
  this.$refs.videoPlayer,
  this.options,
  function onPlayerReady() {
    console.log("onPlayerReady", this);
  }
);
this.player.one("loadedmetadata", () => {
  var duration = this.player.duration();
  console.log(`Duration of Video ${duration}`);
  console.log(`Original Width of Video ${this.player.videoWidth()}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As you're using jQuery, that can be done much easier :) You can use [$.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to edit the html contents of a dom element. Your code will look something like this:

```
<div id="duration"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    _V_("vemvo-player").ready(function(){
        var myPlayer = this;
        var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
        $('#duration').html('Duration: ' + howLongIsThis);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It still says that duration is 0. How i can show the real duration?

Comment: what do you see in the console when executing logging the `howLongIsThis` var?

Comment: What do you mean in console? I don't get it.

Comment: Why it sais it's = 0 where is the problem?

Comment: How i can execute this in console?

Comment: [What is console.log and how do I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: I have used Opera Dragonfly and just typed `howLongIsThis` and i get `Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: howLongIsThis`

Comment: And when i only place `myPlayer.duration()` its shows = `252.002` and i this is the duration in seconds..

Comment: can you update your question with the exact code you have now?