# How to display Javascript/Jquery value in HTML page? VideoJs Display durration of the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi there i am currently working on HTML5 Jquery video player.
Here you can get more info about this HTML video player: http://www.videojs.com/docs/api/

From this link you can see that `myPlayer.duration()` is the function that must show the video durration in seconds. And that's it i just want to display this value in simple HTML page like i am trying with my code.

This is my code:

```
 <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <video id="vemvo-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay="true" width="950" height="534"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="[var.base_url]/uploads/[var.video_play]" type='video/flv' />
  </video>
<div id="duration"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myPlayer = _V_("vemvo-player");
    _V_("vemvo-player").ready(function(){
        var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
        $('#duration').html('Duration: ' + howLongIsThis);
    });
</script>
```

The problem with this code is that it's showing `Duration: 0` when the video duration is far from 0.

My video player is working okey and it's showing durration of the video correctly.
My question is how  i can show this durration in HTML page value?

With the code above when i post `var myPlayer = _V_("vemvo-player");` into `_V_("vemvo-player").ready(function(){` function and i try in the console to run `myPlayer.duration()` it gives me error for Undefined variable, but when `var myPlayer = _V_("vemvo-player");` is outside the function like it is in my post and i type `myPlayer.duration()` in the console it's giving me the durration in seconds like i need it.

The problem is that i can display this variable as a number in HTML page.
I just want to display this number in HTML page.

Where is the mistake in my code and how i can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking how to run that code again after the video loads.

Comment: I don't know if that is needed to show the duration?
How i can display that duration?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221029/problem-retrieving-html5-video-duration
You probably don't have the metadata yet so that function will always give 0. Note: the answer below the accepted one is probably what you want.

Comment: So what i must change in my code to make it work and how it will look like?

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [How to print one specific Javascript variable in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910095/how-to-print-one-specific-javascript-variable-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPlayer = _V_("vemvo-player");
_V_("vemvo-player").ready(function(){
   // Any ready/init code you want here
   $('#duration').html('Duration: ');        
});
myPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    $('#duration').html('Duration: ' + myPlayer.duration);
});
</script>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221029/problem-retrieving-html5-video-duration)

Comment: How i can make this whole script work so the Duration will be shown?

Comment: I have replaced with your updated code but it's still not working. Now it's even not showing `Duration:` text.

Comment: Thank you mate, but it's still NOT working. Now the result is only `Duration:` and not displaying any value after it..

Comment: You should be able to get it to work with the `addEventListener` it just might take some work because I don't have your code base I can't debug. Good luck

Comment: The code in the answer is "listening" to `myPlayer` for an event called `loadedmetadata`, gets the `myPlayer.duration` value and then puts the number in the HTML.

Comment: I have tried this code from the answer but it's not working. So what i have to do? Mate you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to keep the variable declaration outside the function, but the assignment inside?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPlayer;
    _V_("vemvo-player").ready(function(){
        myPlayer = _V_("vemvo-player");
        var howLongIsThis = myPlayer.duration();
        $('#duration').html('Duration: ' + howLongIsThis);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It still says: `Duration: 0`